# Combining simple QUERIES in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table that looks as follows `service`:

```
id | service           | status | multicall | date_created         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
10 | Cleaning          |    1   |      0    |  2016-09-20 19:11:01 |    
11 | Gardening         |    1   |      0    |  2016-09-20 19:12:07 |
12 | Dishes            |    1   |      1    |  2016-09-20 19:14:28 |    
13 | Take out rubbish  |    1   |      1    |  2016-09-20 19:14:28 |
```

This a a table that users can can select service from that they want someone to do.
Once the service is finished, the user history gets saved in a different table `user_service_hist`:

```
id | user_id | service_id | date_created         |
--------------------------------------------------
1  |    1    |     10     |  2016-11-25 10:49:05
2  |    1    |     11     |  2016-11-27 23:58:46
3  |    1    |     12     |  2016-11-28 00:01:36
4  |    1    |     13     |  2016-11-28 12:07:17
```

The user can only select each service once EXCEPT the service marked with a `multicall column` value of `1`.

When I call the list of available service I use the follwing query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.service, s.date
from service s WHERE not exists (Select 1 from user_service_hist ush    
where ush.service_id = s.id AND ush.user_id = 1)
```

This query selects zero rows as I the user has completed all services.
I would like to display service nr. 12 and 13 always as these have a multicall column value of 1, regardless of whether it was completed or not.
Could someone tell me how to modify my query?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple "OR s.multicall = 1" suffice?

Comment: @Stefan I think hank is right. isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the  query with an union for multicall

```
  SELECT s.id, s.service, s.date
  from service s WHERE not exists (Select 1 from user_service_hist ush    
  where ush.service_id = s.id AND ush.user_id = 1)
  union 
  SELECT s.id, s.service, s.date
  from service s WHERE multicall  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two conditions for available services:

- The user has not used the service previously.
- The service is multi-call.

You just need to include both in the query.  The second goes in the `where` clause as an additional condition:

```
select s.*
from service s 
where not exists (Select 1
                  from user_service_hist ush    
                  where ush.service_id = s.id and ush.user_id = 1
                 ) or
      s.multicall = 1;
```

Comment: Hi I think that this should work. Unfortunately I have other conditions in my first WHERE clause. I did not mention these to simplify the query. When I try to run the new query with the OR clause at the end my server runs into an inifinite loop and says "Loading...." in phpMyAdmin